# Link Azure Web App to a specific folder in my git repository

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-web-app-service, github-actions

I am working on a solution which consists of 3 projects:

- Api
- Shared
- Web

Each project exists in it's own own folder, with the same names as above, and the solution file is in the root folder (just outside the 3 folders)

On Azure, I have created a Web App service which is linked to my githib repository which contains all 4 folders above.
I am using Git Hub Actions for CI/CD.

When I publish my /Api project, Azure can successfully build the the solution and project.  However, when I navigate to the Web App url, I get the default holding page.

Is there some way by which I can link the Web App service to run the project in the Api folder so that all requests are routed to the compiled app in that folder?  I can get this to work if I publish my Api in root of my repository but I was hoping to organise the projects in my solution into folders.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [customize your deployment](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Customizing-deployments)

> You can specify the path to the project file, relative to the root of your repo. Note that this is not a path to the solution file (.sln), but to the project file (.csproj/.vbproj). The reason for this is that Kudu only builds the minimal dependency tree for this project, and avoids building unrelated projects in the solution that are not needed by the web project.
>
> Here is an example:
>
> ```
> [config]
> project = WebProject/WebProject.csproj
> ```

You need to place `.deployment` file at the root of the repository

> Deployment configuration files let you override the default heuristics of deployment by allowing you to specify a project or folder to be deployed. It has to be at the root of the repository and it's in .ini format. Here are some examples: